# How do I reuse/import a local variable to another place in my code?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to make Tic Tac Toe with swift in Xcode.

I have a constant for a button that needs to be inserted nine times to make the Tic Tac Toe board. When I have the constant in my initialiser, the board is created as it should, however I can't access the button's properties in my function for when one of them is pressed.

If I try to create the constant outside the initialiser, I can call it in my function, however it only creates one button on the last tile in the board (the down-right corner).

On another note, I'm trying to make some spacing between the buttons, however it only moves the whole board instead of spacing out in between the buttons, so if you could help me with that too it would be great.

```
    import UIKit

class TicTacToeClass: UIView {


    var turn = 0 //0 = X's turn, 1 = O's turn
    var tileType = 0 //0 = empty, 1 = X, 2 = O
    var row = 0 //0 = row1, 1 = row2, 2 = row3
    var column = 0
    let spacing = 5
    let tiles = 9 //number of tiles
    let emptyTile = UIImage(named: "emptyTile")


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)


        for _ in 0..<tiles {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

            button.frame = CGRect(x: 0+column*100+spacing, y: 0+row*100+spacing, width: 100, height: 100)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            button.setImage(emptyTile, forState: .Normal)
            button.setImage(emptyTile, forState: .Highlighted)
            button.setImage(emptyTile, forState: [.Normal, .Highlighted])
            button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
            button.addTarget(self, action: "setTile", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
            print("row: \(row), column: \(column)")

            addSubview(button)

            if row == 0 {
                if column == 0 || column == 1{
                    column++
                }
                else if column == 2 {
                    row++
                    column = 0
                }
            }
            else if row == 1 {
                if column == 0 || column == 1{
                    column++
                }
                else if column == 2 {
                    row++
                    column = 0
                }

            }
            else if row == 2 {
                if column == 0 || column == 1{
                    column++
                }
                else if column == 2 {
                    row++
                }

            }
            else {
                print("****")
            }
        }

    }

    func setTile() {
        if turn == 0 {
            print("test X")
            //button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()


            turn = 1
        }
        else if turn == 1 {
            print("test O")
            //button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

            turn = 0
        }
        else {
            print("****")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the button when you create it in the `initialiser`, just change something like:

```
// button.addTarget(self, action: "setTile", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
button.addTarget(self, action: "setTile:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
```

Then

```
        //func setTile() {
        func setTile(sender:UIButton!) {
            // sender is the pressed button. You can do everything with it.
            if turn == 0 {
                print("test X")
                //button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

                turn = 1
            }
            else if turn == 1 {
                print("test O")
                //button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
                sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
                turn = 0
            }
            else {
                print("****")
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't see a change in the first part, is that correct?
Also, when I use the sender in my setTile function, I get an error when I press any of the buttons. (Thread 1: signal SIGABRT)

Comment: @StevoHN `"setTile"` -> `"setTile:"`. Notice the "`:`"

Comment: Oh, I'm a bit new. Would you mind telling me what difference it makes?

Comment: Does it work now? "setTile" means you don't pass any parameter to `"setTile"` function, "setTile:" means you will pass 1, and it is the button call `addTarget`

Comment: Yes it works now, thanks a lot. And okay, I think I get it.
Could you eventually also help me with my spacing problem?

Comment: @StevoHN If you have any problem just post a new question. : ) .

Comment: @StevoHN. Ok. So what is your spacing problem? You can add my skype: anhtudev